# TF2 Private Server won't work with friends

Tags: team-fortress-2, hosting

So I was looking at a tutorial on how to play with friends in a private server but and my friends are still unable to join. How do I let my friends join my private server?

Comment: Could you add the tutorial you've been following to your post? That would make it easier to determine what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

You have to forward ports in your router. Commonly you can reach your routers configuration at http://192.168.1.1 but it differs, your firewall might also be blocking connections. Ports that need forwarding seems to be:

- UDP 27015
- TCP 27015
- UDP 27020
- UDP 27005

(TCP and UDP 27015 should be the only required ones according to Valve: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8571-GLVN-8711)

Also enable the developer console and enter `sv_lan 0` when you have started your private game.

Comment: Can you tell where you got the list of ports from, and why one would need to enable the developer console and enter `sv_lan 0`?

Comment: Ports were taken from https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Linux_dedicated_server, sv_lan 0 is pretty standard when hosting Valve games, just tells the server that's it's not a LAN server.

Comment: Found a Valve KB on required ports, added a clarification to the post.